# Keep all records from one table when using UNION ALL with other table

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, union-all

My two tables - `UserLog` and `UserInspection` such that `UserLog UNION ALL UserInspection`.

I want to keep all records from `UserLog` but want to keep some records from `UserInspection` whose `OWNER` value *is same as* `column owner` value.

**Illustration:**

```
String OWNER = "0394850935803";

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = 
         new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

HashMap<String, String> dataMap = null;

table_log = "SELECT Type_Log, Start AS SortDate, Location, 
             Remark, Odometer, NULL AS Start_odo, NULL AS owner 
             FROM UserLog WHERE deleted !=1 ";

table_insp = "select Type, Date, Location, Observation, NULL, 
              Start_odo, owner from UserInspection where deleted !=1 ";

final_query = table_log + " UNION ALL " + table_insp + " ORDER BY SortDate";

cur = dbAdapter.rawQuery(final_query, null);

cur.moveToFirst();

for (int j = 0; j < cur.getCount(); j++)
{
    /*Keep all the UserLog records but keep only*/
    /*those UserInspection records whose owner column value*/
    /*from cursor matches the OWNER String value*/
    if((cur.isNull(cur.getColumnIndex("owner"))) 
     || OWNER.equals(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("owner")))){

      /*Code to get other column values*/
      dataMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
      dataMap.put("Location", location);
      list.add(dataMap);
    }
}
```

But I am getting nothing in the *`ArrayList list`* even when `UserLog` table is having some records.

Comment: I would bet your error is coming from your orderby clause.  Your second query doesnt have `SortDate`, so it will throw an error.

Comment: @paqogomez there might be only one `ORDER BY` for `UNION`, so it's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the additional condition into the WHERE clause, then you do not need to check it in your code:

```java
...
table_insp = "select Type, Date, Location, Observation, NULL, "+
             "Start_odo, owner from UserInspection "+
             "WHERE deleted !=1 "+
               "AND owner = ?";

final_query = table_log + " UNION ALL " + table_insp + " ORDER BY SortDate";
String[] parameters = new String[] { OWNER };

cur = dbAdapter.rawQuery(final_query, parameters);
...
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote you more for such a simple solution. Thanks Sir.

Answer (score 1):

If you can deal with having the second table's contents as additional columns, then use a `left outer join`:

```
select *
from (SELECT Type_Log, Start AS SortDate, Location, 
             Remark, Odometer, NULL AS Start_odo, NULL AS owner 
      FROM UserLog
      WHERE deleted <> 1
     ) table_log left outer join
     (select Type, Date, Location, Observation, NULL, 
             Start_odo, owner
      from UserInspection
      where deleted <> 1 
     ) table_insp
     on table_log.owner = table_insp.owner;
```

If you really want separate rows, you can use `with`:

```
with table_log as 
      SELECT Type_Log, Start AS SortDate, Location, 
             Remark, Odometer, NULL AS Start_odo, NULL AS owner 
      FROM UserLog
      WHERE deleted <> 1
    ),
     table_insp as (
      select Type, Date, Location, Observation, NULL, 
              Start_odo, owner
      from UserInspection ui
      where deleted <> 1 and
            exists (select 1 from table_log where ui.owner = table_log.owner)
     )
select *
from table_log
union all
select *
from table_insp;
```

Comment: Keeping all the records from left table using LEFT OUTER JOIN is fine but there is no connection between the left table owner and right table owner so the where clause `table_log.owner = table_insp.owner` will never be true. Instead I want to use `OWNER` string value to match with `table_insp.owner`. How can I use this string value in your queries.